# How to initialize the Github API with an API token?

Tags: javascript, api, github

I'm trying to get a file from a github repo purely from JS. What do I need to do to initialize the connection with my API token? Also, do you need a API token just to get a single file from a repo via the API?

Or maybe I'm not meant to use the Github API directly from JS; This [github help page](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) says that tokens are like passwords, then I suppose I'll have to make an AJAX/GET request to a server-side script, and the said script should then request the data I need from github?

This is the code I am using to get a certain file from the repo.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/:rhino/:rhino.github.io/master/:README.md",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(results){
       var content = results.data.content;
       alert(content);
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need. If you use [gh3.js](https://github.com/k33g/gh3) you can request the contents of a file without an access token. This [sample file](https://github.com/k33g/gh3/blob/master/samples/05-file.html) has all the code you need. Download/clone to desktop and pop open in a browser.